# scipy griddata interpolation returns a vector filled with nan

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list of points on in 3d that I would like to interpolate on a 3d grid.

```
coords = array([[  8.33399963,  12.94800186,  15.22500038],
       [  8.57299995,  13.90000153,  14.14700031],...)
```

I have the grid x,y,z coordinates, which together with `numpy.meshgrid` are used to create the grid:

```
xi,yi,zi = np.meshgrid(bbox[:,0],bbox[:,1],bbox[:,2])
```

and then when I try to perform the interpolation:

```
griddata(coords,np.random.choice([.1,1,2],size=len(coords)),(xi,yi,zi),method='linear')
```

I get a vector of nans:

```
array([[[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]],....
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what `xi,yi,zi` values are but most likely they are outside the domain defined by `coords`. If you use `meshgrid` to generate the grid, then pay attention to the order of the arrays:

> In the 3-D case with inputs of length `M`, `N` and `P`, outputs are of shape `(N, M, P)` for `‘xy’` indexing and `(M, N, P)` for `‘ij’` indexing.

Try this:

```
In [61]: coords = 20 * np.random.random((200, 3)) - 1

In [62]: xi, yi, zi = np.meshgrid(np.arange(coords[:, 0].min()+2, coords[:,0].max()-2), np.arange(coords[:, 1].min()+2, coords[:,1
    ...: ].max()-2), np.arange(coords[:, 2].min()+2, coords[:,2].max()-2), indexing='ij')

In [63]: griddata(coords,np.random.choice([.1,1,2],size=len(coords)),(xi.astype(np.float), yi.astype(np.float), zi.astype(np.float
    ...: )),method='linear')
```

You will still get some `nan` values where points poorly sample the function but most values are defined.

Another possibility is that you are just seeing the first "plane" which may contain mostly `nan`. Try `np.sum(np.isfinite(g))` to see how may points are valid out of all points `np.prod(g.shape)` where `g` is thr output from `griddata()`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like my error was this: `np.meshgrid(bbox[:,0],bbox[:,1],bbox[:,2])`. Instead, I should have used linspace or arange like this: `np.linspace(np.min(bbox[:,0]),np.max(bbox[:,0]))`, etc.