# Scipy griddata with 'linear' and 'cubic' yields nan

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

the following code should produce griddata. But in case I choose as interpolation type 'cubic' or 'linear' I am getting nan's in the z grid. Wen i'm choosing 'nearest' everything is running fine.
Here is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x = np.array([0.03,0.05,0033])
y = np.array([0.004,0.01,0.02])
z = np.array([1,2,3])


xy = np.zeros((2,np.size(x)))
xy[0] = x
xy[1] = y
xy = xy.T

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0.0:0.09:250*1j, 0.0:0.03:250*1j] #generating the grid


i_type= 'cubic' #nearest, linear, cubic
grid_z = griddata(xy, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method=i_type)

#check if there is a nan in the z grid:
print np.isnan(grid_z).any()
```

I don't have any idea why this is not working..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy griddata interpolation returns a vector filled with nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812319/scipy-griddata-interpolation-returns-a-vector-filled-with-nan)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your area you look at is simply much larger than your input points. This doesn't matter for 'nearest' as this always puts the nearest value to a certain coordinate. But 'linear' and 'cubic' do not extrapolate but fill the values which are not within the input area with nan by default.

See also the docs of `griddata`:

```
fill_value : float, optional
Value used to fill in for requested points outside of the convex hull of the input points. If not provided, then the default is nan. This option has no effect for the ‘nearest’ method.
```

Best understandable when plotted by `imshow`:

[image]

plot created with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x = np.array([0.03,0.05,0.033])
y = np.array([0.004,0.01,0.02])
z = np.array([1,2,3])


xy = np.zeros((2,np.size(x)))
xy[0] = x
xy[1] = y
xy = xy.T

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0.0:0.09:250*1j, 0.0:0.03:250*1j] #generating the grid

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)
for i, i_type in enumerate(['cubic', 'nearest', 'linear']): #, cubic
    grid_z = griddata(xy, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method=i_type)

    #check if there is a nan in the z grid:
    axs[i].imshow(grid_z)
    axs[i].set_title(i_type)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer !

Comment: What module import do you use for plt?

Comment: @SpghttCd coul you please explain how is it possible to acess the interpolated points. Say the value at `grd_x[0],grid_y[2]`? `griddata` returns a 2d array and it is not so obvious to me how that maps to the interpolation points given by `grid_x, grid_y`